# R dataframe and columns of type list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, time-series

I have a list of product (P1, P2, P3,...Pn) and for each product I have   five time series of different length. So, I'm looking for sane way to model this dataset through a dataframe structure in R . Maybe a dataframe with one column for product (e.g., id column) and one column of type list for each time series ?

Thank you

EDIT MWE:

I have a folder with 12 files. Each file contains a specific time series of product price. For example, file P1T1 contains time series T1 for a product P1.  List of product (P1,P2,P3,P4), names of time series (T1,T2,T3):

`files_names=list.files("/data")`

the code above give the names of all files ("P1T1","P1T2","P1T3",...,"P4T3")

`products=unique(str_sub(files_names,1,2))`
 `series_names=unique(str_sub(files_names,3))`

The two lines above give the unique names of products and time series respectively.

Now, I try to read all file and create dynamically a dataframe that contains a column for product names, and three other columns of type list corresponding to the three time series of each produc:

```
 data=setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5,nrow = 0)),c("product",series_names))

for ( product in products){
         for ( ts in series_names)        
                 read.csv(paste(product,ts,sep=""), col.names = ("value"))
}
```

Comment: Please create a reproducible (minimum working) example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please see the edit, thank you